# Vim in iTerm 2 Losing Color on Restart

Tags: vim, iterm

I have an issue with using Vim within iTerm.  Works as expected first time but any restart or new instance of iTerm and everything is broken.  Take this as an example

Download and open iTerm and get default theme

[image: fresh launch]

Next import the solarized dark colour scheme

[image]

Then fire up vim and open a file

[image]

Everything is as expected.  Now quit all instances of iTerm and reopen

[image]

Command line is as expected.  Now open vim and open the same file.

[image]

Broken.  Has any one seen something like this before?

UPDATE

Now if I install the solarized color scheme in Vim the results look different again.

[image]

This scheme is acceptable (even go as far to say correct) but my question is where do the original colors come from then and how can i set those as default?

Comment: My .vimrc https://github.com/kouphax/vim-files/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: If you switch the theme back to one of default ones and restart and dot the above process all over again you get the same issue.

Comment: Also worth mentioning removing all custom vim config produces the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the COLORFGBG environment var. It's set based on whether the background is light or dark. COLORFGBG=0;15 gives you the before screen and COLORFGBG=12;8 gives you the after screen.

Comment: This is exactly the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand, iTerm is terminal emulator, so you probably use terminal version of vim, however your .vimrc contains no colorscheme settings for this version, only for gui. Try moving

`set colorscheme solarized`

outside

`if has('gui running')`

Comment: This is very true.  HOWEVER my real question is where does the second image (the first vim launch) get its colors from and why do they change?

Comment: No idea, but you can try :verbose hi Boolean to learn where does highlighting for Boolean come from (Boolean was what autocompletion proposed to me first, try other syntax groups too).